# Embeded code block error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Embeded code blocks like

```
<% if (something == 1) %>
    <input value="something" />
<% else %>
    <input value="not something" />
```

has always worked but stopped after installing VS2012. Why?

The error is 
 CS1525: Invalid expression term 'else'

Comment: Yes, that works. Sorry should have put that in the question. I can wrap { } but didn't have to until the vs2012 install. The question is why? Is there a setting that changes the behavior?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
<% if (something == 1) {%>
   <input value="something" />
<%  } else {%>
   <input value="not something" />
<%  }%>
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Sorry should have put that in the question. I can wrap { } but didn't have to until the vs2012 install. The question is why? Is there a setting that changes the behavior?